# Swap background on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, playframework

I'm trying to swap background using jQuery. But the problem is that it doesn't successfully switch to new background, instead, the old one is removed and I get a white background instead.

I've been googling and trying out putting the path as a var instead for example, and some other unsuccessful suggestions.

My jQuery function looks like the following:

```
$("#btn").hover(function () {
    $('#page1').css('background-image','url(../images/bg1_normal.jpg)');
});
```

And my CSS for the default background looks like this:

```
#page1 {
    height: 100vh;
    max-height: 100vh;
    background-image: url("../images/bg1_rw.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

I'm using `Java Play Framework` and the pictures are in the same folder, and it is the **correct path** to it since the default background works.

**EDIT:** I Tried as well to use an img source from the web, just to be 100% sure it wasn't some issues with the path, but it still only makes it white.

Comment: Sure, realized that right after I posted :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try .addClass and .removeClass functions - it's simple and all style work is done in stylesheet file:

```
$("#btn").on({
    mouseenter : function() {
        $('#page1').addClass('inverted');
    },
    mouseleave : function() {
        $('#page1').removeClass('inverted'); 
    }
});
```

and then simply add

```
#page1.inverted {
    //style as you need
}
```

to your stylesheet.

Answer (score 2):

I believe jQuery's `hover()` function isn't able to remove that particular style when the mouse leaves.

You could just do it yourself

```
$("#btn").on({
    mouseenter : function() {
        $('#page1').css('background-image','url(../images/bg1_normal.jpg)');
    },
    mouseleave : function() {
        $('#page1').removeAttr('style'); 
        // or simply set the backround again to the other image
    }
});
```

Comment: It makes it return to the normal background at least when the mouse leaves, but still switches to a white background only on entering.

Comment: If the image is where it's supposed to be, it shouldn't do that

Comment: That's very odd, I'm 100% sure it's the correct path to the image, and it is there. Checked it at least 10 times since it was the first thing that popped into my mind.

Comment: You are right actually, it does work with the web URL. But the funny part is that the picture really is in that folder. Maybe because the jQuery is applied after the build, and then the image is in another folder actually?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using images you could do an image swap like this

https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/oee3guxz/

```js
$("#flowers").mouseover(function () {
    var _this = $(this);
    var current = _this.attr("src");
    var swap = _this.attr("data-swap");
    _this.attr('src', swap).attr("data-swap",  current);
   _this.toggleClass("opaque");
});
```

```css
.opaque {
    opacity:.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id='flowers' class="full" src='http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/snowdrops.jpg' width="500" height="400" data-swap='http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/daisies.jpg'  width="500" height="400" />
```

or if you could just use color like this

```js
$("#color").mouseleave(function () {
         $("body").css("background-color","black");
});
$("#color").mouseover(function (){
         $("body").css("background-color","red");
});
$("#color").click(function(){
     $("body").css("background-color","green");
});
```

```css
body, #color {
    height: 800px;
    width: 800px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="color">&nbsp;</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/8p783jfo/

Hope this helps

Rach